# Find and Replace text using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that will automatically import data from a csv. However, every time the script runs, the data being pulled has the word "undefined" in cells that were blank.

Is there a way to fix this by making appends in the script. If not, is there a way to append any script to find and replace the word "undefined" and replace it with a blank?

Here's the current code I am using for the fetch (which I also got here):

[How to automatically import data from uploaded CSV or XLS file into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854563/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-uploaded-csv-or-xls-file-into-google-sheet?lq=1)

And here's the link where the find and replace script was suggest:

[How to replace text in Google Spreadsheet using App Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877554/how-to-replace-text-in-google-spreadsheet-using-app-scripts)

Not quite sure where to add the find and replace function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!