# Can't find a way to replace a part of text in cell from a column with Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

For some reason, the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877554/how-to-replace-text-in-google-spreadsheet-using-app-scripts) doesn't work for me. Here is my whole code that should replace the 'PPP' with 'nothing'

```js
function tests() {
  // I need to replace more occurrences of different strings, so this is just an example..
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("F22:F24").getValues();
  var test = [];
  // this is a loop, to go through multiple cells that may contain the text, that needs to be replaced.
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    var le = range.length;
    var stri = range[i].toString().replace("PPP", "");
    test[i] = stri;
  }

  //range.setValues(test);
  ss.getRange("F22:F24").setValues(test);
  
  var msg = ui.alert("Replaced?");
  return msg;
```

I tried a couple of things with `setValue`, `setValues` and simply with `=` and nothing... With the code above I get this error

> Cannot convert Array to Object[][]

There must be a simple way to replace strings with App Script, considering that in Google Spreadsheets you can simply `CTRL + H` and replace any text with any text you want...

(I know I must learn Javascript, but time is now very tight...)

Comment: Forgot to mention - I need to replace multiple strings in cells from a column... every replacement is the same and the cells are from the same column. This means that I will use the same code a couple of times in one script.

Comment: Whats the output of range[i]?

Comment: The output depends on the [i] variable, but mostly the every cell contains a text, similar to this: >ProducătoPPPr:BlackBerry:1;Model:Z30:2;Generația conexiunii:4G:3;Diagonala display (inch):5.0:5;Multitactil:Da:6;Rezoluție (pixeli):720 x 1280:8;Tip ecran:Super AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors:9;SIM:Single SIM:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ss.getRange("F22:F24").setValues(test);
```

array `test` in your example is one-dimensional array but should be two-dimensional. So you just need simply to change the line:  `test[i] = stri;` with `test[i] = [stri];` and you code will work.

Comment: Thank you! This really does work, but it replaces only one found instance, but if the string, that needs to be replaced, is found a couple of times in the same string, this code will replace only the first instance. 
Is there a way to replace all the instances without drastically complicating this code? Or is it easier to run the same code 3-4 times?

Comment: Yes, you can use Regular Expression to fnd all matches of string in another string globally:

`for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) { var find = "PPP"; var regex = new RegExp(find, "g"); var stri = range[i].toString().replace(regex,""); test[i] = [stri]; }`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!