# Replace Text in Sheet Values without Changing Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with values like these:

```
8504.40.9031    9403.70.0000
8504.40.9090    9403.70.8031
8504.40.9510    9403.70.9000
```

I am trying to use a script to find and remove the periods (".") in each value so that the end result is this:

```
8504409031  9403700000
8504409090  9403708031
8504409510  9403709000
```

I've been trying to execute the below script to achieve this:

```
function appendString() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
var writeValues = []
for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
  var row = []
  for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
    var currentValue = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
    var withString = currentValue.toString().replace(".","");
    row.push(withString)
  }
  writeValues.push(row)
}
range.setValues(writeValues)
}
```

I've encountered the following issues that I can't resolve and where any help is greatly appreciated:

1) the script only removes some periods, and

2) the script removes trailing zeros (I assume the script reads it as float values so removes the trailing zeroes, but I don't know how to correct this). The undesired end result I get with this script is:

```
850440.9031 940370
850440.909  940370.8031
850440.951  940370.9
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try replacing `"."` with regex  `/\./g`

Comment: Review the syntax of the JavaScript method `String#replace` on your preferred JavaScript language reference to help yourself understand the current behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'-'I 's comment answered my question.  Issue was failure to use regex. Corrected  `var withString = currentValue.toString().replace(".","");` to   `var withString = currentValue.toString().replace(/\./g,"");` and success.

In case anyone runs into a similar issue, I was trying to build off of this answer which did not use RegEx:

[How to replace text in Google Spreadsheet using App Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877554/how-to-replace-text-in-google-spreadsheet-using-app-scripts)