# Can I use Google Apps Script to replace text across multiple tabs in a Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building on [a previous project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021245/using-google-apps-script-how-can-i-replace-text-in-a-google-sheets-template-to/68022822) in which I have a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAyA6zASzOX-o5noqLWKk9wGpeQXf6LWP5_EBXvi1ufH_N0w/viewform) which takes responses in a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17qtLpnFTiMoE6blELSTQhtxkWa1hjjzI_PcaY-3cS1Q/edit?resourcekey=null#gid=465252365) and uses a [template Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wqCwMhpuDLReU1hE1CbcDL-Vdw_4zge1xM6oOl34Ohg/edit?usp=sharing) to populate the Form responses and have that generate a new Sheet document. This is a very dumbed-down version of what I'm trying to execute in reality, but the goals remain the same: I am trying to replace text across multiple tabs in the template Sheet when generating a new one.

Currently, in my [Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1z1hOdOUyUVntZDxlQvWIE3PizyOM5tULbUecaIt7WqOubmmG76LdYe9F/edit), I have code which is successfully able to make a copy of the template file and name it accordingly:

```
//Enter collected info into Requirements Template
      const googleSheetTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1wqCwMhpuDLReU1hE1CbcDL-Vdw_4zge1xM6oOl34Ohg');
      const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1GxNZQmP8mxHBhVl5AMoqBFs8sAIYzcm3');

      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');

      const copy = googleSheetTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[3]}, ${row[0]} Vehicle Order` , destinationFolder);
      const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy.getId());
      const A1 = newSheet.getDataRange();
```

And the next few lines which are meant to be able to find and replace certain strings within the newly copied Sheet are as follows:

```
  A1.createTextFinder("{{Customer}}").replaceAllWith(row[3]);
  A1.createTextFinder("{{Car}}").replaceAllWith(row[1]);
  A1.createTextFinder("{{Color}}").replaceAllWith(row[2]);
  A1.createTextFinder("{{Delivery}}").replaceAllWith(row[5]);
```

The issue I am experiencing is that the first tab of the Sheet gets populated, but the second tab does not.

Is there more I must add somewhere in order to get the second tab filled out? Is this even possible in Google Apps Script?

---

Entire code below:

```
function myFunction() {
    // get the spreadsheet information
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //const responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');
  const data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  //console.log(data);

  // Loop over the rows
  data.forEach((row,i) => {

    // Identify whether notification has been sent
    if (row[4] === '') {

      // Get the Form info
      var emailTo = "jeffreyabr@gmail.com"
      var subject = 'Car Request';
      const Timestamp = row[0];
      var Car = row[1];
      var Color = row[2];
      var requestor = row[3]
      var delivery = row[5];

      //Form variable declarations
      formTime = Timestamp;
      formCar = Car;
      formColor = Color;
      formName = requestor;
      formDelivery = delivery;

      //Enter collected info into Requirements Template
      const googleSheetTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1wqCwMhpuDLReU1hE1CbcDL-Vdw_4zge1xM6oOl34Ohg');
      const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1GxNZQmP8mxHBhVl5AMoqBFs8sAIYzcm3');

      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');

      const copy = googleSheetTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[3]}, ${row[0]} Vehicle Order` , destinationFolder);
      const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy.getId());
      const A1 = newSheet.getDataRange();

      A1.createTextFinder("{{Customer}}").replaceAllWith(row[3]);
      A1.createTextFinder("{{Car}}").replaceAllWith(row[1]);
      A1.createTextFinder("{{Color}}").replaceAllWith(row[2]);
      A1.createTextFinder("{{Delivery}}").replaceAllWith(row[5]);


      const orderLink = newSheet.getUrl();
      //Add URL to Sheet
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue(orderLink)

      orderBlob = [];

      //Get the blob of order attachment
      if(row[6]){
        var order1 = row[6].split(', ');
      
        order1.forEach(url => {
          var orderFileId = url.replace('https://drive.google.com/open?id=','');
          var orderFile = DriveApp.getFileById(orderFileId);
          orderBlob.push(orderFile.getBlob());
        });
      }


      let body = '';

      // Generate email
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
      var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
      
      // Send email
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, body, {htmlBody: htmlText, attachments: orderBlob})

  // Mark as Notified
  const g = 'Notification sent';
  ss.getRange(i + 1,5).setValue(g);
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: row is undefined.  Yes we want you're code to be minimal but it also has to be reproducible. Try again. I don't like following links.  If you want my help post everything I need in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have copied and pasted my entire code into an update at the bottom of the original post. I can update with more screenshots of the Sheets and Forms if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

- You can try a looping method to access all of the sheet tabs inside of your `newSheet` Spreadsheet file using the [***`getSheets()`***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) method.

> Just replace part of your script from the creation of `newSheet` to the last line of `A1.createTextFinder` with the script below:

### *[UPDATED]*
Sample Script

```
  const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy.getId());
    
  for (currentSheet = 0; currentSheet < newSheet.getSheets().length; currentSheet++) {
    const a1 = newSheet.getSheets()[currentSheet].getDataRange();
    a1.createTextFinder("{{Customer}}").replaceAllWith(row[3]);
    a1.createTextFinder("{{Car}}").replaceAllWith(row[1]);
    a1.createTextFinder("{{Color}}").replaceAllWith(row[2]);
    a1.createTextFinder("{{Delivery}}").replaceAllWith(row[5]);
  }
```

### Sample Test:

> **Sample copy of the `newSheet` file w/ 2 sheet tabs**

[image]

[image]

> **Script test demonstration**

[image]

> **The `newSheet` file that contains 2 sheet tabs:**

```
Sheet 1
```

[image]

```
Sheet 2
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error that reads: `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable` after I have added the code you recommended. This error is in reference to the line `for (sheet = 0; sheet < newSheet.getSheets().length; sheet++) {` 

If you didn't see already, I copied and pasted my entire code in the end of the original post.

Comment: Got it, yes, I have updated my script & changed the "sheet" in the for loop to "currentSheet". It looks it has interfered with the line sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue(orderLink).

Comment: Winner! Thanks so much! Works in my example as well as my primary application. Perfect.